# Added SSL to client side server but still not performing handshake with backend server nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, security, ssl, tls1.2

I am trying to implement SSL on my nodejs project. Currently, my servers are split between a client side server running on localhost port 443 and a backend server running on localhost port 5000. I have already added a self-signed SSL certificate by openSSL to my client side server as shown below.[image: SSL cert]

Now here's my issue. When I send a post request to login, from what I understand, a handshake is suppose to happen between the server and the client to make a secure connection. However, that's not the case. When I used Wireshark the intercept the packets, there is no handshake happening in the process.

[image: Wireshark tracing login API packet]

I am currently not sure on how to proceed because I have limited knowledge on this kind of security topics. Do I need to sign a new key and cert and add it to my backend server? Or am I doing everything wrong? If so, can I get a source or guide on how to properly create one for a nodejs server?

Answer (score 0):

you have many options here for securing  your backend server :

first, you can use Nginx reverse proxy server and you can add ssl/tls logic to it. nginx will handle this stuff for you.

second, you can use [https][1] package directly and pass your SSL certificate and key to it :

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

remember that the domain name your are trying to access must be set in your host ip.
[1]: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html